# Sitecore & Oracle: 'Unhandled Execution Error' while connecting

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I'm trying to run Sitecore 7 with Oracle and I'm stuck on an error. What I've done is

- Let a DBA create all Oracle users / schemas / tables
- Verified with Oracle SQL Developer that the databases are indeed created, accessible and containing tables
- Make sure I'm using the correct web.config
- Update my connection strings
- Do all the other Sitecore setup that I would normally do (IIS site, VS solution, etc.)
- Install Oracle Client tools (including all possible drivers for my 64-bit system)

I've tried two variations of connection strings:

> user id=my_username;password=my_password;Data
>   Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=my_host_name)(PORT=5151))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=my_service_name)))

and this one:

> Data Source=my_username/my_password@//my_host_name:5151/my_service_name

Using the exact same information, I'm perfectly able to connect using the Oracle SQL Developer.

When I launch my Sitecore site, I get the following exception:

**Unhandled Execution Error**

*Exception Details: Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException:*

> [OracleException (0x80004005)]
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32
>   errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx*
>   pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck, Int32
>   isRecoverable) +1250
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode,
>   OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src) +91
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open() +4698
>   ....snipped...

Been struggling with this for a day now and would really appreciate some help.
Anyone out there running Sitecore 7 on Oracle?

Comment: Which revision you are running? Sitecore 7.0 initial release(rev. 130424) doesn't support Oracle. You need at least Sitecore 7.0 update 1(rev. 130810) to run Oracle.

Comment: I'm running the latest revision.

Comment: Do you see any Oracle error ID, typically "ORA-{numeric code}" followed by an error message, in the exception details? Knowing an error ID will help troubleshoot. You may try following instructions in this post if you don't see it: http://chilledflame.wordpress.com/2012/03/28/oracleexception-0x80004005-but-no-error-message/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you are using the Oracle client tools version 11g, other Oracle versions are not supported with Sitecore 7.
See [this link](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%206/Installation/CMS%20compatibility.aspx) for a reference

Comment: I had version 12g of the Data Access Tools installed. Removed that and installed 11g and it's working fine now. Thanks!